# How can I set structure members from a tuple without using match?

Tags: rust

I want to initialize two fields from a tuple returned from a function:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    z: f64,
}

fn f() -> (f64, f64) {
    (5., 6.)
}

fn main() {
    let mut p = Point {
        x: 1.,
        y: 2.,
        z: 3.,
    };
    println!("{:?}", p);
    match f() {
        (x, y) => {
            p.x = x;
            p.y = y;
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", p);
}
```

The obvious code `(p.x, p.y) = f()` did not compile so I have to use `match`. Do you have any idea how to make the `match` assignment simpler to read?

I want to

1. Call `f` only once per assignment of the two fields
2. Have `f` on the right side, and `p.x` and `p.y` and the left side, not how it is in `match` now

Comment: You could do `let (x,y) = f(); p.x = x;  p.y = y;` .

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```rust
let (x, y) = f();
p.x = x;
p.y = y;
```

You can put similar patterns in `let`s that you can put in `match`es.

Comment: I expect something without introducing new variables

Comment: @user1244932 then the answer is, unfortunately, "no".

Comment: @user1244932 you could put it in a block

Comment: How about a new method or function, so that you'd write `p.setxy(f())`?